# Is it possible to use mod_expires in an Apache configured as reverse proxy?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, cache

my setup is as follows:

*Browser* **<=>** *Ec2 Load Balancer* **<=>** *Apache (reverse proxy)* **<=>** *Jetty*

The Apache and the Jetty are running on the same machine in the Amazon cloud (Debian Lenny, Linux appinstance 2.6.21.7-2.fc8xen-ec2-v1.0 #1 SMP Tue Sep 1 10:25:30 EDT 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux). The Apache version is 2.2.9. The Jetty version is 6.1.26.

What I'm trying to achieve is basically what Google calls [Perfect Caching](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#perfect_caching)

My Apache config currently looks like this:

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /xxx http://localhost:8080/xxx
ProxyPass /yyy http://localhost:8080/yyy
ProxyPass / http://localhost:9080/

ProxyPreserveHost On

<Files *.nocache.*>
    ExpiresActive  On
    ExpiresDefault "access"
</Files>

<Files *.cache.*>
    ExpiresActive  On
    ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 year"
</Files>
```

Currently my ExpiresDefault rules are ignored entirely. I googled for quite a while without any luck.

Is it even possible to combine mod_expires with mod_proxy? If yes: What am I doing wrong? Otherwise: Are there any feasible alternatives?

Cheers!
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use LocationMatch, not Files.  Files refers to actual filesystem files, not what looks like a filename int he last component of a URL.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!

This is what my config looks like now:
 <LocationMatch .*\.nocache\..*>
  ExpiresActive  On
  ExpiresDefault "access"
 </LocationMatch>
 
 <LocationMatch .*\.cache\..*>
  ExpiresActive  On
  ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 year"
 </LocationMatch>